# Tkinter - Scrollbar grids but window isn't properly sized

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

I'm attempting to use a tkinter scrollbar with my canvas and I am able to have the scrollbar post and it is scrollable with the `scrollregion` command, however I cannot maintain that the window is properly sized.

I'd like the window to be height of 300 and width of 500 but the window is posting to the extent of the `Frame`s and `Label`s, rather than receiving the height of 300 and width of 500 from the `Canvas` command.

```
        self.windows["project_management"] = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas = {
            "main": tk.Canvas(self.windows["project_management"], width = 500, height = 300,scrollregion = (0, 0, 1000, 1000))
            }
        # WORKBENCH
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].scrollbar_y = tk.Scrollbar(self.windows["project_management"], orient = tk.VERTICAL, command = self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].yview)
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].scrollbar_y.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.S)
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"]["yscrollcommand"] = self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].scrollbar_y.set
        # / WORKBENCH
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas_ordinate = [
            self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"],
        ]
        for i, x in enumerate(self.windows["project_management"].canvas_ordinate):
            x.grid(row = i, column = 1)
        directory = self.variables["main"]["project_directory_bin"].get()
        print("Directory: {directory}.".format(directory = directory))
        path = pathlib.Path(directory)
        print("Directory Path: {path}.".format(path = path))
        json_files = []
        # WORKBENCH
        for i, x in enumerate(path.iterdir()):
            print("Path: {path}.".format(path = x))
            xx = str(x).split(".")
            if xx[1] == "json":
                json_files.append(x)
        print(json_files)
        content = []
        for i, x in enumerate(json_files):
            with open(str(x), "r") as file:
                json_file = json.load(file)
            content.append(
                    {
                        "complete_time_strftime": json_file["complete_time_strftime"],
                        "full_duration": json_file["full_duration"],
                        "initial_time_strftime": json_file["initial_time_strftime"],
                        "task": json_file["task"],
                    }
                )
        # HEADER ROW
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate = [
            tk.Frame(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"]),
        ]
        self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[0].labels_ordinate = [
            tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[0], text = "Initial Time" + " |"),
            tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[0], text = "Complete Time" + " |"),
            tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[0], text = "Objective" + " |"),
            tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[0], text = "Duration"),
        ]
        # / HEADER ROW
        for i, x in enumerate(content):
            self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate.append(tk.Frame(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"]))
            self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i + 1].labels_ordinate = [
                tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i + 1], text = content[i]["initial_time_strftime"] + " |"),
                tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i + 1], text = content[i]["complete_time_strftime"] + " |"),
                tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i + 1], text = content[i]["task"] + " |"),
                tk.Label(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i + 1], text = content[i]["full_duration"]),
            ]
        for i, x in enumerate(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate):
            # (i + 1) as header row exists
            x.grid(row = i, column = 0)
            for ii, xx in enumerate(self.windows["project_management"].canvas["main"].frames_ordinate[i].labels_ordinate):
                xx.grid(row = 0, column = ii)
```

Image of the window:

[image: screenshot of window]

Comment: Please provide a standalone *runnable* [mre] (MRE).

Comment: It is because you used `grid()` to put the frames into canvas.  `Canvas.create_window()` should be used to put the frames instead.